# Umbraco Template not saving

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, templates, web, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco version 7.3.7 assembly: 1.0.5878.19872 and everytime I try to create and save a new template it will not allow me to save the template.  I get a SERVER ERROR in '/' Application message saying No node exists with id '2689'.  It seems this problem is only when trying to create a new template.

UPDATE 2/13/2017

I am getting this error message on my development server and production server.

Comment: Have you looked in the App_Data/umbracoTraceLog.txt for any extra clues? I also seem to remember having trouble creating and saving templates if a template was somehow duplicated. Can you check to see if you have any templates with duplicate aliases?

Comment: When I am able to click on the template and change the alias it does one of three things, 1. It shows me the error message listed above 2. It will not save  3.  When I click save it removes the template from my template list

Comment: It is almost like the save button is not responding at all.

Comment: Does that mean you found a duplicate?

Comment: Nope, no duplicate.

Comment: Is this on your local pc, or on a live version? You need to ensure Umbraco has write-permissions in order for it to create and save files.

Comment: It is on the live version.  And only the live version.  We have two servers, a development server and production one.  I can save and create fine on the development one but when I push to the production server its not going over into Umbraco.  I can save and create templates fine in development.